# Difference between RMI URL formats

Tags: java, rmi

I've seen 2 types of RMI URLs(may be this term is incorrect) as `http://host:port/rmi` and `rmi://host:port/repository_name`. But I've no idea what the difference between those two are. can someone please explain?

Thanks.

Comment: The RMI protocol is being used in the second one. I might be able to answer better if I knew what RMI is.

Comment: More like "better understood"

Comment: What do you mean by `if I knew what RMI is.`?

Comment: I mean I don't quite understand what RMI is.

Comment: @Bhathiya Nevertheless he gave you the right answer. It's obvious even when you don't know what RMI is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've seen 2 types of RMI URLs(may be this term is incorrect) as `http://host:port/rmi`

I've been using RMI for fifteen years and I've never seen anything like that described as an 'RMI URL'. Where did you get that from?

> `rmi://host:port/repository_name`

Now *that* is an RMI URL.

Comment: See here http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/RemoteAccess#RMI
It says the difference, but I don't get it.

Comment: @Bhathiya That's tied to a specific product, and it isn't described as an 'RMI URL'. The word 'URL' doesn't even appear on the page.

Comment: That's why I mentioned `(may be this term is incorrect)` in my original post. I just wanted to get an explanation on those two.

Answer (score 3):

The format of an RMI URL is one of the following:

```
   rmi://[host][:port][/[object]]

   rmi:[/][object]
```

If the object name is absent, then the URL names the registry at the given host and port. Otherwise, it names the remote object registered at that registry under the name provided.
If the host is omitted, the local host is assumed. If the port is omitted, the default registry port 1099 is assumed.

[ref this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-rmi.html)